# Using ViewModel inside a Custom WebView in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-custom-view, android-livedata

I have a custom WebView that I handle several items inside that to load a specified java script commands.
in addition I have some logics in its WebViewClient inside the Custom WebView and I don't want to define and set WebViewClient in my fragment.
I need to be announce whenever the "onPageFinished" called from WebViewClient, so I use a LiveData in my WebView and I observe that in my fragment.
is this a best practice and right way?

that is like this:

```
class MyWebView : WebView {
 private val _loadPageFinished = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
 val loadPageFinished: LiveData<Boolean> get() = _loadPageFinished

//setWebViewClient
    webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                _loadPageFinished.postValue(true)
            }
}

}
```

and in Fragmennt is like this:

```
class MyFragment:Fragment(){

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        webview.loadPageFinished.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,Observer{

         //do something when page loading finished here
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that will work perfectly.

Comment: yeah, seems that's okay